# some question of combination

Tags: combinatorics, algebraic-geometry

we know that hilbert seris of n- variables polynomial ring is  $\Sigma_{i} \binom{n-1+i}{i}t^{i}$

But, I don't know $\Sigma_{i} \binom{n-1+i}{i}t^{i}=(1-t)^{-n}$.

I wonder to prove in detail.

Comment: The left hand side also gives the coefficient of $t$ as $n$ instead of $-n$, so you possibly want a $(-1)^i$ as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the modifications in my comment, we can write the right hand side as
$\frac{1}{(1 - t)^n} = (1 + t + t^2 + \ldots)^n$.
Now the coefficient of $t^i$ in $(1 + t + t^2 + \ldots)^n$ is the number of ways to distribute $i$ identical objects to $n$ distinct containers, which is the coefficient of $t^i$ on the left hand side.